# paho.mqtt.client publish topic has additional forward slash

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I'm usuing paho.mqtt.client to forward a local mqtt broker to another public mqtt broker,
so what I did is, have two client, and subscribe on both, and on receive mqtt message, forward to another borker, the issue I have is it will always has a  additional forward slash in the forwarded mqtt message topic.

the original message topic:
elevator/11112901/cabin/load/actual-load

[image]

the forward message topic:

elevator/11112901/cabin/load/actual-load/

[image]

Appreciate if you could share your comments,thanks!

**The code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding=utf-8
import hmac
import queue
import base64
from hashlib import sha1
import time
from paho.mqtt.client import MQTT_LOG_INFO, MQTT_LOG_NOTICE, MQTT_LOG_WARNING, MQTT_LOG_ERR, MQTT_LOG_DEBUG
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt
import random
import string

dev_key = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, 12))

# 实例 ID，购买后从产品控制台获取
instanceId ='xxx'

#账号AccessKey 从阿里云账号控制台获取
accessKey = 'xxx'

#账号secretKey 从阿里云账号控制台获取
secretKey = 'xxx'

#MQTT GroupID,创建实例后从 MQTT 控制台创建
groupId = 'xxx'

#MQTT ClientID，由 GroupID 和后缀组成，需要保证全局唯一
client_id=groupId+'@@@'+ dev_key

#MQTT 接入点域名，实例初始化之后从控制台获取
brokerUrl='xxx'

topic_elevator_command = 'commands/#'
topic_elevator_status = 'elevator/#'
q = queue.Queue()



def on_log_aliyun(client, userdata, level, buf):
    if level == MQTT_LOG_INFO:
        head = 'INFO'
    elif level == MQTT_LOG_NOTICE:
        head = 'NOTICE'
    elif level == MQTT_LOG_WARNING:
        head = 'WARN'
    elif level == MQTT_LOG_ERR:
        head = 'ERR'
    elif level == MQTT_LOG_DEBUG:
        head = 'DEBUG'
    else:
        head = level
    print('%s: %s' % (head, buf))


def on_connect_cube(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print('Connected with result code ' + str(rc))
    client.subscribe(topic_elevator_status, 1)
    client.publish("elevator/test", "32q14324")


def on_message_cube(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic + ' ' + str(msg.payload))
    if msg.topic.startswith(topic_elevator_status[:len(topic_elevator_status)-2]):
        q.put(("Cube", msg))

def on_disconnect_cube(client, userdata, rc):
    if rc != 0:
        print('Unexpected disconnection %s' % rc)


def on_connect_aliyun(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print('Connected with result code ' + str(rc))
    client.subscribe(topic_elevator_command, 0)
    client.publish("elevator/test", "32q14324")


def on_message_aliyun(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic + ' ' + str(msg.payload))
    if msg.topic.startswith(topic_elevator_command[:len(topic_elevator_command)-2]):
        q.put(("Aliyun", msg))


def on_disconnect_aliyun(client, userdata, rc):
    if rc != 0:
        print('Unexpected disconnection %s' % rc)
client_aliyun = mqtt.Client(client_id, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311, clean_session=True)
#client_aliyun.on_log = on_log_aliyun
client_aliyun.on_connect = on_connect_aliyun
client_aliyun.on_message = on_message_aliyun
client_aliyun.on_disconnect = on_disconnect_aliyun
## username和 Password 签名模式下的设置方法，参考文档 https://help.aliyun.com/document_detail/48271.html?spm=a2c4g.11186623.6.553.217831c3BSFry7
userName ='Signature'+'|'+accessKey+'|'+instanceId
password = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(secretKey.encode(), client_id.encode(), sha1).digest()).decode()
client_aliyun.username_pw_set(userName, password)
# ssl设置，并且port=8883
#client.tls_set(ca_certs=None, certfile=None, keyfile=None, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS, ciphers=None)
client_aliyun.connect(brokerUrl, 1883, 60)
client_aliyun.loop_start()

client_cube = mqtt.Client(dev_key, clean_session=True)
#client_cube.on_log = on_log_aliyun
client_cube.on_connect = on_connect_cube
client_cube.on_message = on_message_cube
client_cube.on_disconnect = on_disconnect_cube
client_cube.connect("xxx",1883)
client_cube.loop_start()

while 1:
    qmsg = q.get()
    dir, msg = qmsg
    print(dir, msg.topic)
    if dir == "Cube":
        client_aliyun.publish(msg.topic, msg.payload)
    if dir == "Aliyun":
        client_cube.publish(msg.topic, msg.payload)
```

Comment: I have tested your code (with small modifications required to get it running) between two public brokers (`broker.emqx.io` and `broker.hivemq.com`) and was unable to duplicate your issue (the messages received were as expected). What output are you getting when you run the program? (e.g. `Aliyun commands/blah`).

Comment: The mqtt message payload is fine, only issue is the topic, one additional separator was added in the forward message.  I debugged the code, the received message is also ok, the parameters for publish is also correct, not sure why.

Comment: Please try it with the public brokers I used (using something like `mosquitto_sub`/`mosquitto_pub` to publish/subscribe messages) and if you still have the issue post an updated [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With what you have provided I've been unable to duplicate the issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try later today and update you accordingly, thanks again for your comments!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i tired those public brokers, it's working without this issue, so it should be the issue with the Aliyun mqtt broker, thanks.